# Microsoft excel problems, cross-table

Tags: excel, database, windows

I wanted a cross-tab solution in which the main table extracts data from sub-tables. In my version, there are classes grouped into categories. The 11.A class is the main table, and there are sub-classes like 11.A info, engineering, etc. I would like Excel to find the student, and if an "X" is entered for them at a given time, it should also be handled in the main 11.A class table.

**Main table**

[image]

**11AD info table**

[image]

11.07 etc is the date 2023.november 07. From 0 to 8, it indicates during which class the student was absent.

This is how I understand it: if I check a specific part of a table and there is an "X" entered for a student, it should copy the "X" value; otherwise, it should leave it blank. However, I would like to fill this in for several hundred student records.

Do I have any options for this, or am I thinking about it incorrectly? Thank you in advance for any response.

This is not the best solution because i have got like 200 students that i want to add to this excel sheet.

```
=IF('11 AD info'!B4="X","X","")
```

I want to check sub-class for X if the student is missing, search them by name.

Comment: A formula like `=IF(('11 AD Info'!B3="X")+('11 AD Engineering'!B3="X"),"X","")` would detect an X in any of the individual classes, and 'summarise' it on the main sheet, but its impossible to advise on doing this for several students, because your screenshots look like each is only for a _single_ student